# Rewrite rules for making multiple paths work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a requirement to make the following paths work. 
Depending on what the url consists of, they are mapped to go to different java classes.

`/books/`
`/books/science/`
`/books/science/fiction/`
`/books/science/fiction/kids/`

So, I have given the rewrite rules in my configuration file as:

`^/books$`
`^/books/(.*)$`
`^/books/(.*)/(.*)$`
`^/books/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$`

but the moment I give a url something like this

`http://localhost/books/science/fiction/kids/12345`

instead of getting captured by the fourth rewrite rule, it is captured by the second one which is not what I want.

Can someone please tell me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

`^/books$  /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ABCController?resultsFor=allCategories [PT,QSA]`
`^/books/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/XYZController?make=$1&resultsFor=category [PT,QSA]`
`^/books/(.*)/(.*)$    /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ABCDController?format=$1-$2&resultsFor=subCategory [PT,QSA]`
`^/books/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$   /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ASDFController?resultsFor=product [PT,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava ``^/books$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ABCController?resultsFor=allCategories [PT,QSA]``

Comment: ``^/books/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/XYZController?make=$1&resultsFor=category [PT,QSA]``

Comment: ``^/books/(.*)/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ABCDController?format=$1-$2&resultsFor=subCategory [PT,QSA]``

Comment: ``^/books/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ASDFController?resultsFor=product [PT,QSA]``

Comment: Click on edit link below your question and provide paste your .htaccess there not in comments

Comment: _“instead of getting captured by the fourth rewrite rule, it is captured by the second one”_ – of course it is, because the dot matches _any_ character, so slashes as well. Replacing it by a character class allowing anything _but_ a slash (and demanding at least one character out of that class, so `+` instead of `*`) should fix that, `([^/]+)`

Comment: Another way would be to reverse the order of your rules … You should always write them in order from most to least specific anyway.

Comment: OK, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> instead of getting captured by the fourth rewrite rule, it is captured by the second one

That’s because the dot matches *any* character, so slashes as well.

Replacing it by a character class allowing anything *but* a slash (and demanding at least one character out of that class, so + instead of *) should fix that: `([^/]+)`

Another way would be to reverse the order of your rules … You should always try and write them in order from most to least specific anyway.